# Finding the stationary points and their types

Tags: self-learning, partial-derivative

I am trying to calculate the local maximum and minimum of $f(x, y) = x$<sup>$3$</sup>$y$<sup>$2$</sup>$(2 − x − y)$, however I seem to keep running into issues.

My steps were to find the partial derivative for $f$<sub>$x$</sub>$(x,y)$ and $f$<sub>$y$</sub>$(x,y)$, then find the values for y and substitute them back to find x. After that I found $D=f$<sub>$xx$</sub>$(x,y)$$f$<sub>$yy$</sub>$(x,y)$-[$f$<sub>$xy$</sub>$(x,y)$ ]<sup>2</sup> to determine the type of stationary point.

I think most of my problems stem from incorrectly identifying the stationary points to begin with, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you determin gradient of $f(x,y)$ you will get
$$[6x^2y^2-4x^3y^2-3x^2y^3,4x^3y-2x^4y-3x^3y^2]$$
$$[x^2y^2(6-4x-3y),x^3y(4-2x-3y)]$$
Finding the stationary points will give you $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $(x,y)=(1,\frac{2}{3})$

Comment: I found the (0,0) roots by simply by concluding that outer y must equal zero, but I can't get the inside to give me the solution y = 1

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You just have to solve the system of linear equations $6-4x-3y=0$ and $4-2x-3y=0$.